# USGS Bulk Downloader cannot locate install4j

Tags: java, landsat, usgs, earth-explorer

Trying to run the the USGS' Bulk Download Application (https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/earthexplorer-bulk-download-application-bda) and keep getting an error message that it could not find the JRE. I choose the options presented to locate it and  navigate to my JAVA folder and the java.exe file. Error persists. Java is installed.
any ideas?

previous to this I set the JAVA_HOME and another related environment variable to the java jre folder.

Comment: Update: I was an idiot and was using Java 1.8 instead of Java 10+. Though I did need to get an archived version of Java from oracle. Also you do not need to register for an account with them - just right click on the green download button and select save as. Last thing - point the locate a jre error message to the Java 10+ unzipped folder that has a java.exe in it. And there ya go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JRE_HOME` environment variable instead of `JAVA_HOME` as you may have installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and not the JDK (Java Development Kit) as explained at https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-792499849.html

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Java 10+ JDK is the key thing.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE downloads have different version numbers than the JDK downloads.  Only the JDK downloads are greater than version 10.

The default Windows download from USGS is 32 bit.  Good luck finding a 32 bit JDK download.  Read the fine print on the [USGS download site](https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/bulk).  There is an option to download for other operating systems where you can choose 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was install an archived version of Java JDK. I was able to find it here on oracle's site.
Java SE 13 Archive Downloads (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk13-archive-downloads.html)

Make sure you download the "Windows x64 Installer". I did not have to restart my computer.